# How get the best features from caret GA?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, feature-selection

I'm getting started with **CARET GA feature selection**:

How I get feature final/best selected feature?

I want to use like:

```
gbmFit1 <- train(Class ~ [best feature here], data = training,
                 method = "gbm",
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

code below:

```
    ga_ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = rfGA,
                       method = "repeatedcv",
                       repeats = 5)

## Use the same random number seed as the RFE process
## so that the same CV folds are used for the external
## resampling. 
set.seed(10)
rf_ga <- gafs(x = x, y = y,
              iters = 200,
              gafsControl = ga_ctrl)
rf_ga
```

Comment: The word "dynamic" is vastly overused to the point where it is basically meaningless. Please edit your question to state specifically what is needed.  A data example is probably going to be needed. Posting failed code is a prescription for ... failure.

Comment: @42- just did! thanks for the attention...

Comment: You can get an estimate of the variable importance. This can help you to select the most important parameters. You will have to run your model again with the most important features and check the resulting accuracy and compare it with the previous model. It may be above or below of the model with the previous features. For you to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically,

you just need to call this variables:

> rf_ga$optVariables
>
> bestFeatures <- rf_ga$ga$final

and will return the **best** selected features.